# Hovering over an img element allows document scrolling in Firefox

Tags: html, image, firefox, scroll, hover

I am developing my portfolio website but I am encountering some issues in different browsers. When I go to the website in Firefox and hover over an img element scrollbars pop up and suddenly I can scroll through the entire document (left, right, up and down). I feel like this is a Firefox issue since I only encounter this issue there and not in any other browsers.

You can find the website here [nadiasportfolio.tumblr.com](http://nadiasportfolio.tumblr.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#NEW").delay(250).fadeIn(1000);
  $("#MEDIA").delay(850).fadeIn(1000);
  $("#NEWB").delay(1600).fadeIn(1000);

  //    $(".thumbnail").each(function(i){
  //        $(this).attr("id", "thumbnail" + i);
  //    });

  $(".content").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("id", "content" + i);
  });

  $(".thumbnail").addClass("color-hover");
  $(".pdf").addClass("color-hover");
  $(".content > img").addClass("color-hover");

  $(".content").hide();
  $("#toggleHeader").html("");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("header").trigger('click');
  }, 3000);

  $("header").on("click", headerScrollUp);
  $("header a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("#toggleHeader").on("click", headerScrollDown);

  $(".thumbnail").on("click", toggleContent);

  $(".pdf").on("click", changeSizePDF);

});



var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on("resize", function(event) {

  //    "if (x !== undefined){}" -> does not scroll back to horizontal 0 
  //     but is all over the place

  //    if (x !== undefined) {
  scrollToCurrent = ($(window).width() * 1.015 * x - $(window).width());
  $("section").animate({
    scrollLeft: scrollToCurrent
  }, 10);

  $(".pdf").children("img").css("height", "8vh").css("width", "auto").css("cursor", "zoom-in");

  //    }
});

var x;
var scrollToCurrent;

function headerScrollUp() {
  $("header").animate({
    height: "0vh"
  }, 1000);
  $("#toggleHeader").html("≡");
}

function headerScrollDown() {
  $("header").animate({
    height: "100vh"
  }, 1000);
  $("#toggleHeader").html("");
}

function toggleContent() {
  if ($(this).next(".content").is(":hidden") === true) {
    x = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    //        scrollToCurrent = ($(window).width() * 1.0 * x - $(window).width());
    console.log(this);
    scrollToCurrent = (($(this).width() + 8) * x - ($(this).width() + 8));
    $("section").animate({
      scrollLeft: scrollToCurrent
    }, 500);
    $(this).delay(500).next(".content").show();
    $(this).parent().siblings().css("opacity", "0");
    $("section").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
    $("section").css("overflow-y", "initial");
    $("section").animate({
      scrollTop: viewportHeight / 2 + "px"
    }, 500);
    $(".toggleText").css("transform", "scaleY(-1)");
    //        $(".toggleText").animate({transform: "rotate(90deg)"}, 500);
  } else {
    //animatie werkt niet ??
    $(".toggleText").css("transform", "scaleY(1)");
    $("section").animate({
      scrollTop: "-=1000px"
    }, 100);
    $(this).delay(100).next(".content").hide();
    $(this).parent().siblings().css("opacity", "100");
    $("section").css("overflow-x", "initial");
    $("section").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
  }
}

function changeSizePDF() {
  if ($(this).children("img").height() < viewportHeight / 9) {
    var heightBig = $(this).children("img").height() * 9;
    var widthBig = $(this).children("img").width() * 9;

    $(this).children("img").animate({
      height: heightBig,
      width: widthBig
    });

    $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-out");



  } else {
    var heightSmall = $(this).children("img").height() / 9;
    var widthSmall = $(this).children("img").width() / 9;
    //            var ratioToSmall = (viewportHeight / 100 * 8) * $(this).children("img").width() / $(this).children("img").height();

    $(this).children("img").animate({
      height: heightSmall,
      width: widthSmall
    });

    $(this).css("cursor", "zoom-in");
  }
}
```

```css
.iframe-controls-container,
.iframe-controls-container--logged-in,
.tmblr-iframe,
.tmblr-iframe--desktop-logged-in-controls,
.iframe-controls--desktop {
  display: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.color-hover {
  filter: grayscale(255);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(255);
}

.color-hover:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4vw;
}

h2,
nav a {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  margin: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

code {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  /* change scrollbar space */
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}


/* optional: show position indicator in red */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff00bf, #ff00e9, #b600ff, #9000ff, #3f00ff, #0d00c9);
}

#posts {
  display: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #ddddff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-overflow: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: 40vh;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav a {
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  height: 98vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#toggleHeader {
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ddddff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

article {
  /*    background-color: darkgray;*/
  width: 100vw;
  height: 99vh;
  display: inline-block;
  /*
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
*/
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 99vh;
  background: radial-gradient(skyblue, midnightblue);
  /*    background-size: cover;*/
  background-size: 50vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

#tn-window-of-sounds {
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/RyIom7lgk/window_of_sounds_logo.svg");
  background-size: 50vh;
  /*    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}

#tn-lets-make {
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/dcb2c0ecd7663664d00208b793aeec93/tumblr_ome08qJX761w34hfho3_r1_1280.png");
}

#tn-jumbo {
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/1baf77332e4ae9873da8dbf483870f5e/tumblr_omnx7cJ38U1w34hfho2_r1_540.png");
}

#tn-do {
  /*gif:*/
  /*    background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/26FmRuwDb5eFOPDZS/source.gif");*/
  /*    still image:*/
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/4a4f6f8f43e3a3d8ab6ef29967d47491/tumblr_omnu22CYIt1w34hfho1_1280.png");
}

#tn-van-gogh {
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/fe28945f60e1d27d89b03f79661b7f1a/tumblr_omo650hbbp1w34hfho1_1280.png");
}

#tn-data-visualisation {
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/Yonomo9jy/ballonnen_met_mens.svg");
}

#tn-nature-tour {
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/7e0c4cc06b662fca87201399ad134d64/tumblr_omocqygQIu1w34hfho1_1280.png");
}

#tn-insect-stamps {
  background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/3c3d875629cd2ced500c9c59c288ca61/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho9_1280.jpg");
}

.textWrapper {
  width: 40vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textWrapper:hover {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: thin;
}

.thumbnail h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.toggleText {
  background: url("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/615573-200.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  height: 7.5vw;
  width: 7.5vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30vh;
  /*    z-index: -1;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 5vh;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  display: none;
  width: 90vw;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.content p,
.content code {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

.content p {
  padding: 5vw;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
}

.content>img {
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  visibility: visible;
}

.background-color-white {
  background-color: white;
}

.pdf {
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-overflow: scroll;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.pdf img {
  height: 10vh;
  width: auto;
}

embed {
  width: 100vw;
}

.embed-code {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  background-color: gray;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}


/*{CustomCSS}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nadias portfolio.</title>

  <!--        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, Nadia, van, Leur, CMD, communication, &, and, multimedia, design, jquery, student, javascript, html, css">
  <meta name="author" content="Nadia van Leur">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--
        {block:Description}
            <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
        {/block:Description} 
-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Nadias portfolio.</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Resume</a>
      <a href="/nederlands">Nederlands</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="toggleHeader" class="color-hover">
    ≡
  </div>
  <section>
    <!--Window of Sounds app -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-window-of-sounds">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Window of Sounds</h2>
          <h3>Think further than the frame.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content1">
        <p>Window of Sounds is an app created for Het Noordbrabants Museum. A museum about the art history of Noord-Brabant.<br></p><br>
        <img src="foto mensen koptelefoon"><br>
        <img src="foto mensen koptelefoon"><br>
        <img src="foto mensen koptelefoon"><br>
        <embed class="embed-code" src="http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/nSiomo27n/index.js.txt">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!-- Visuele identiteit Let's Make -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-lets-make">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Let's Make</h2>
          <h3>Visual Identity.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content2">
        <p>Test tekst2</p><br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/23c916b7cf86e27103acee1e21bc6938/tumblr_ome08qJX761w34hfho1_1280.png">
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/30c0e288a6e406d54792441f9c498c75/tumblr_ome08qJX761w34hfho2_1280.png">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--Jumbo shopping app -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-jumbo">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Shopping app design</h2>
          <h3>Jumbo supermarket.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content3">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <div class="pdf">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/1baf77332e4ae9873da8dbf483870f5e/tumblr_omnx7cJ38U1w34hfho2_r1_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/07340d2e8a0fa3279d19685c5d2efe2a/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho9_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/589f872342e4900461e3feb9779d0276/tumblr_omnx7cJ38U1w34hfho1_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/71d4d216751e80c4ff59cb16be2f8676/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho8_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/5b9968c37295813a3321dc5c965e6c96/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho10_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/ea1523e56ac76ae2b2bc35ab5a035823/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho7_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/aa814e094d3aeead9106393b7a644d05/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho6_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/02add0021cf9bae65d227056e133b45e/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho2_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/1eea370bdf68eabeec685f4609b8660d/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho3_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/65b545b972450f03be3aed4f91fb58ba/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho5_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/8eaaa91a977d9d9f083375f9c25b296d/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho4_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/4452fecce1b47f3eb3785c4634154f71/tumblr_omo0gfTM8I1w34hfho1_1280.png">
        </div>
        <div class="pdf">
          <!--                        wireframes-->
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/bd85af7bc33d967c3bc1d2c3a652cb0c/tumblr_omob6m2joz1w34hfho2_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/99379cfa879f8933b324dc19ec1eff40/tumblr_omob6m2joz1w34hfho4_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/b93a861e995036681bca011466728e12/tumblr_omob6m2joz1w34hfho1_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/b65291e59aafa734d45e71afe6577471/tumblr_omob6m2joz1w34hfho3_1280.png">
        </div>
        <div class="pdf">
          <!--                        flowchart-->
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/5cf04fbf473771e3ad12bc35c37ef9df/tumblr_omoa1vsBJz1w34hfho1_1280.png" class="background-color-white">
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--Do - to do list -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-do">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Do</h2>
          <h3>Your interactive planning buddy.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content4">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <video controls>
                        <source src="https://nadiasportfolio1.tumblr.com/video_file/t:iXG2gnAz8wfzNTNiBot6bQ/158063052645/tumblr_ome2pg5G361w34hfh/480" type="video/mp4">
                    </video><br>
        <embed class="embed-code" src="http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/u8xomeeab/code_week_7.5.txt">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--Van Gogh museum concept -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-van-gogh">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Vincent van Gogh</h2>
          <h3>Museum concept.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content5">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/fe28945f60e1d27d89b03f79661b7f1a/tumblr_omo650hbbp1w34hfho1_1280.png"><br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/35adcb40d7794ff87a24f6c1137dea18/tumblr_omo650hbbp1w34hfho3_r1_1280.png"><br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/1aefc3bee07b76fbc2a77e42ea21987c/tumblr_omo650hbbp1w34hfho2_r1_1280.png">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--Festival data visualisation -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-data-visualisation">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Festival fun</h2>
          <h3>Data visualisation.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content6">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/ZMgomo9ik/ballonnen.svg"> <br>
        <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6zouj6x/Yonomo9jy/ballonnen_met_mens.svg">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--nature tour concept -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-nature-tour">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Nature tour</h2>
          <h3>Hybrid reality studying.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content7">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/7e0c4cc06b662fca87201399ad134d64/tumblr_omocqygQIu1w34hfho1_1280.png"> <br>
        <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/696f84dadfdbe32a27e465cc32587644/tumblr_omocqygQIu1w34hfho2_1280.png">
      </div>
    </article>

    <!-- Insect stamps -->
    <article>
      <div class="thumbnail" id="tn-insect-stamps">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <h2>Insect stamps</h2>
          <h3>Print design.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggleText"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content8">
        <p>Test tekst3</p><br>
        <div class="pdf">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/41d9fb6e284ba7f2b3250c3ab6df237f/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho1_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/d1353684775c941d446f27cbbcbe2e20/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho2_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/5a7049422a210bfd6662cca2715dec61/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho3_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/f907bae2cb23340dac25a7fcee2086b7/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho4_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/08c51ac81196e4cf97f07d440b187f97/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho5_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/b723a80f40b6a47b1685cbb211ceffe5/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho7_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/13e4fecf712f10b17456c13a9f60f9f9/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho6_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/65c627320107a02f7d611b1cec67cea6/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho8_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/47785b763eafda7a6efa7debaaf03d06/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho10_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/a2770b062c2b80146c4101fb85d03194/tumblr_omt5bdemab1w34hfho9_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/53c925ddb870b2e548e8a542799a2a54/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho1_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/182f16489d01d846c55c3a9022b52ddb/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho2_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/a63baa1ad66ed76657b0a440bc072c18/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho3_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/18574a0a546a587c946b8d1fbd057acb/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho4_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/1c11c92fdd5d594a10b036eb7e8bac48/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho5_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/c2b54fedf1b2903071aca31beba48dbb/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho6_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/2f138adcce9e7b9f884797a5e368863d/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho7_1280.png">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/80a6230cd93c50508bd99bdc9902eaeb/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho8_1280.jpg">
          <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/3c3d875629cd2ced500c9c59c288ca61/tumblr_omt5hkNls91w34hfho9_1280.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>



</html>
```